# Threading within ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, grand-central-dispatch

I have a singleton wrapper class called "Folio APIWrapperv2" that is responsible for handling all of my API data calls within my iPhone app.

This class implements ASIHTTPRequest in order to fetch JSON from my server. When an ASIHTTPRequest has finished, it calls requestFinished:. In this method, I have additional processing of the data that can take a couple of seconds to complete. It's not major, but it slows down the app slightly, as it's a blocking call. To fix this, I create a new thread using GCD. However, when this thread runs, I get the following error:

```
[FolioAPIWrapperv2 respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x245050
```

This function is being called in ASIHTTPRequest's "handleBytesAvailable" method at the line:

```
if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:[self didReceiveDataSelector]]) {
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. FolioAPIWrapperv2 is a singleton class, so it should never be deallocated. I've tried searching online to see what other issues people have had with threading and couldn't find a suitable solution. Does anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the delegate to be an instance of the class or the class itself? The delegate must be an instance of a class.

Otherwise, if you're getting the output:

```
[FolioAPIWrapperv2 respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x245050
```

Then it seems likely that your class that should never be deallocated is getting deallocated.

Either way, at least one way to approach this is to add some debugging, eg, when you create the request:

```
NSLog("set delegate to %p", request.delegate);
```

and similar logging for self in the init/dealloc of your singleton.

Comment: Okay, so I did some testing and I discovered that when the thread calls a method in the singleton, it gets deallocated. If the thread does NOT call the method in the singleton, it works. Do you know what's going on here?

Comment: @MichaelD. Not a clue! Try sticking a breakpoint on the dealloc, and if that fails breakpoint release / autorelease - that should show you the code that's doing the deallocation.